# How to render out a queryset in Django templating?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-channels

I'm creating an inbox where the logged in user can see all of their messages using Django Channels 2.

I would like to render out the queryset in the InboxView in order to return all thread objects for the logged in user.

I am having trouble with the syntax and the threads aren't appearing.

If someone could kindly help me, I would appreciate it.

I would like to render out the queryset in the InboxView in order to return all thread objects for the logged in user.

views.py

```
class InboxView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'chat/inbox.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)
```

models.py

```
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = 
self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs


class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    objects      = ThreadManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.first}'

class ChatMessage(models.Model):
    thread      = models.ForeignKey(Thread, null=True, blank=True, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    user        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
verbose_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message     = models.TextField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'
```

inbox.html

```
  {% for thread in object.thread_set.all?? %}
      <div class="chat_list">
            <h5>{{ thread.second }}<span 
class="chat_date">{{ thread.timestamp }}</span></h5>
            <p>{{ chat.message? }}</p>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that at all. Your view is already based on Thread, so you get an `object_list` containing a queryset of Thread objects.

```
{% for thread in object_list %}
```

The syntax you were trying would useful if you had a DetailView of some other model and were trying to follow a relationship from that object to its list of threads.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. I was using that syntax to retrieve the chat messages in the DetailView for the chat message model and got confused. What would be the syntax if I wanted to render out the last chat message `<p>{{ chat.message? }}</p>`? Would I have to run another forloop as `message` is a field in the `ChatMessage` model?

Comment: Well, then you would indeed have to follow the reverse relation from the thread object, so `{{ thread.chatmessage_set.last.message }}`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just checked out your blog and read up a little bit on reverse relations. I didn't know that the automatic object name for ListViews was object_list ...I have a lot more learning to do...best wishes.